# html radio button checked issue

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have a couple of radio buttons in my application and by default none of them is checked. When I check one of them, and call a javascript to see which is checked, the radio button which is checked does not show checked in JS or HTML Markup(F12). I dont knw what's causing this wierd issue. Kindly assist.

Thanks

EDIT: i'm using the following JS to see if the parent container of the radio buttons has "CHECKED" in its innerHTML.

> if( document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_' +
>   controlid).cells[cv].innerHTML.indexOf("CHECKED") > -1)

Comment: which property do you check? There are properties which doesn't update.

Comment: I just checked the radiobutton from my browser and then on button click I call a JS to see if any of the radio buttons is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to check if a checkbox is checked:

```
if (document.getElementById('checkboxId').checked == true)
    //Code here...
```

The DOM-attribute "checked" does not change when you click the checkbox, it's used to know how it should be initialised.

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery there is a convenient selector for that.

```
$("input:checked").each(function(i,v){
    console.log(v.value);
})
```

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/f369xbt5/3/